# Repaint never reaches paintComponent();

Tags: java, swing, graphics, repaint

I'm back with a problem about java-graphics by swing... I want to paint some stuff at a jframe, here is the code:

PaintUtil-class:

```
public class PaintUtil extends JPanel{

public PaintUtil(){
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocus();
}

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("Repainted");

        g.drawstuff...
    }
}
```

Main-class:

```
public static PaintUtil util = new PaintUtil();

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(500,600);
frame.setRezisable(false);
frame.add(util);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( 3 );
frame.getContentPane().setColor(Color.BLACK);
setup(); //This add some buttons
frame.setVisible(true);

util.repaint(); //not working
util.paintComponent(frame.getGraphics()); //works
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: What does `PaintUtil` extend?

Comment: PaintUtil extended JPanel

Comment: Is your componant actually on screen?

Comment: `util.paintComponent(frame.getGraphics); ` is not how you should be doing painting.  Without a runnable example, it's impossible to know why you're having issues

Comment: `repaint` is nothing more then a request to the `RepaintManager`, which will make decisions about what and when a paint cycle is triggered. There are many reasons why a component might not be painted, most deal with optimisations, like not painting components which are realised on the screen or whose size is `0x0`. We could of course continue to "guess" at the reasons for your issue or you could make a [runnable example which demonstrates your actual problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Set the size of the `JPanel` (`PaintUtil`) and call `frame.pack()` prior to calling `util.repaint()`.

Comment: Can you at least be more specific when saying "This is NOT working", Why ? What happens ? errors ? What is your expected result ?!

Comment: repaint() schecules a paint which calls paintComponent() on JPanel, can you give us more code ?

Comment: There is no error, no message in the console, just nothing... Here is some more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no error, no message in the console, just nothing

```
frame.setLayout(null);
```

Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Get rid of that statement.

By default the size of your panel is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

You will need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your panel so the layout manager can do its job.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Ok now I have eliminated the null layout, but there is still the same problem

Comment: Shoukd I mabey print you the full classes? But only if you concentrate on the problem that I asked and not on other stuff which is not good, I know that ;)

Comment: @Caipi, post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Okey now there is everything nessesary. util.repaint(); is not working and frame.paintComponent(frame.getGraphics()); works but is doesn't delete the old stuff :(

Comment: @Caipi, `Okey now there is everything nessesary` - No it isn't complete. You didn't override getPreferredSize(), so you didn't listen the my suggestion or read the tutorial . You should NOT be invoking repaint() or paintComponent(). Read the tutorial!!! Download the working code and modify it for your requirement.

Comment: Why I have to override the getPreferredSize();????? Other programs with repaint(); are working brilliantly without that stuff!

Comment: Read the tutorial for the proper way to do custom painting!!! Just because something works doesn't mean it is correct or it will work in all situations. Until you post a proper [mcve] I have no further comments.

Comment: Read the tutorial for the proper way to do custom painting!!! Just because something works doesn't mean it is correct or it will work in all situations. All Swing components are responsible for determining their own preferred size so layout managers can do their job. Until you post a proper [mcve] I have no further comments